# Можно ли в tkinter работать с текстом написанным в Text? И если да, то как?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Можно ли настроить tkinter так, чтобы он работал как, например, microsoft word? То есть там можно было бы менять размер шрифта, делать заголовки и подзаголовки, исправлять опечатки, вставлять туда картинки, причем не программистом, а именно пользователем.
Порекомендуйте статьи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Статей не знаю, но вот что может вам понадобится:

```
text = Text(WRAP = WORD) #после применения wrap=word текст будет переноситься по словам
text.insert(1.0, 'some text') #добавление текста в элемент. 1.0 - начало, END - конец
text.delete(1.0, END) #очистка элемента
text.config(state = DISABLED/NORMAL) #если state = DISABLED, пользователь не сможет в него ничего писать
print(text.get()) #с помощью get можно получить данные о написанном тексте в элементе
```